# What's the difference between the verbs "recruit" and "employ"?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between the verbs "recruit" and "employ? Why is it used so in sentences "Our company is flourishing and we recruit more than a handred workers. Every year we employ 10 more."

Comment: 'Recruit' is necessarily inchoative (referring to the hiring process); 'employ' may or may not refer to the hiring.

Comment: What did you find when you looked these words up in the dictionary? They are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

To "recruit" is to "attract" or "sign up." To "employ" is to "use.

All *employees* were *recruited,* but not all *recruits* are (ultimately) *employed*. (Some are "let go" after a short period of time.)

Comment: Employees were not necessarily recruited either.

Answer (score 0):

If you were a small, but successful [head-hunting agency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employment_agency) then you might only ***employ*** a few people, but ***recruit*** dozens of people every week on behalf of your clients.